# Copy directories based on day they were created

Tags: linux, unix

Can you tell me any command to sort / copy / remove the directories  which have been modified (or created, although Linux does not show it) on a particular date i.e. yesterday and they are inside another directory?

Comment: `ls -t` gives you a list of directory contents sorted by time modified. `cp` to copy. `rm` to remove files/folders. you can create a shell script if you'd like to do that and add it on your `cron`.

Comment: I am looking for a single command to find and remove

Comment: It is something like this "find /BACKUP/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec mv -i {} /BACKUP/upload_testlink/ \;"

Answer (score 1):

I would use `find` and specify `-mtime`

so for example

```
cd /var/log/apache2
find *.log -mtime -1  -exec ls -l --time-style=iso {} \;
```

would output the following:

> -rw-r----- 1 root adm 440 09-10 20:00 error.log
>
> -rw-r----- 1 root adm 3944602 09-11 02:08 other_vhosts_access.log

if I wanted to copy them I would do the following:

> find *.log -mtime -1 -exec cp -v {} /tmp/ \;

would output:

> `error.log' ->`/tmp/error.log'
>
> `other_vhosts_access.log' ->`/tmp/other_vhosts_access.log'

more on mtime:

```
For example:

find . -mtime 0   # find files modified between now and 1 day ago
                  # (i.e., within the past 24 hours)
find . -mtime -1  # find files modified less than 1 day ago
                  # (i.e., within the past 24 hours, as before)
find . -mtime 1   # find files modified between 24 and 48 hours ago
find . -mtime +1  # find files modified more than 48 hours ago

find . -mmin +5 -mmin -10 # find files modified between
                          # 6 and 9 minutes ago
```

source: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

Comment: It is something like this "find /BACKUP/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec mv -i {} /BACKUP/upload_testlink/ \;"

Answer (score -1):

You can use piped commands to achieve this. Hope this helps.

```
rmdir `ls -lt | grep -v "\`date '+%h %d'\`" | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Comment: This breaks if a directory has whitespace in its name. Also it's depending on the `date` variant and time formatting.